# How many cores each Hadoop map task use?

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm running Hadoop task on a cluster of YARN with max of 8 tasks and 16 cores.
When I run the job I see 8 tasks running on a node yet all 16 cores been used.
Is map task is multi threaded ? 
Map task use more than 1 core ?
Can I know which cores used each map task ?

Thanks,
Assaf

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the number of cores per map, as well as the maximum number of usable cores - see [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml).

The question sounds a bit confused, so, some more details which may be relevant:

A task might do more than just run a map, and, if you're running hadoop, you might be using the cores with something else in the system (ie, maybe some other process is using the cores).

A mapping task might use more than one mapper to do its job - that's part of the point of using hadoop and a MR architecture - your work will get auto-magically distributed and split for you.

Also, beware, your number of tasks doesn't directly relate to the number of mappers, cores or other resources in use; if what you're looking to do is limit cpu usage, or in any other way control resource allocation, change the properties of your containers.

---

For a more detailed discussion of resource allocation (esp. when compared to MR1) [see here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/migrating-to-mapreduce-2-on-yarn-for-operators/).